# How to implement Bill Me later in asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, paypal, paypal-sandbox

> is there an sandbox account for testing Bill Me Later just like paypal?

Answer (score 0):

BML (PayPal Credit) is now tied into Express Checkout directly.  Just do a regular EC integration, but in your SetExpressCheckout request you'll set the following:

- USERSELECTEDFUNDINGSOURCE=BML
- SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole
- LANDINGPAGE=Billing

So then you can just have two separate buttons on your checkout page, and if they click the BML/Credit button you'll add the extra parameters.

The buyer gets a different experience depending on whether those params are added or not.